# Kivy - Telenium: Error 111 while trying to connect a client

Tags: python, kivy, urllib2, urllib, json-rpc

I'm trying to use [Telenium](https://github.com/tito/telenium) to automate testing of a Kivy app. Per the README.md I've run my application with the Telenium module:

```
python -m telenium.execute main.py
```

Next I've tried to connect to this application using a client:

```
>>> id = cli.pick()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyjsonrpc/http.py", line 168, in __call__
    return self.http_client_instance.call(self.method, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyjsonrpc/http.py", line 259, in call
    debug = self.debug
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyjsonrpc/http.py", line 132, in http_request
    response = urllib2.urlopen(request, timeout = timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 404, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 422, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1214, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1184, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused>
```

To diagnose a bit further, I did the following:

```
>>> cli.url
'http://localhost:9901/jsonrpc'
```

Any help in resolving this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you start your Kivy app at `localhost:9901`?

Comment: @xmcp: I have no idea how to start the Kivy app with a specific URL - I couldn't find anything in the README.md. As I said above, I just called it this way: `python -m telenium.execute main.py`. I guess `locahost:9901` must be default.

Answer (score 0):

Running with your applications `main.py` will solve this issue

[Check the full solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52309628/cli-command-not-working-teleniumhttpexception-method-not-found)

Comment: Rajat jain, this does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](//stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](//stackoverflow.com/tour)